# Kubernetes: auto restart pod if hosted on specific nodepoll

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

### Background

I have two Kubernetes nodepools - `A` and `B`.

`A` nodepool is the right hardware and the preferred one. `B` be nodepool is less preferred since it using different hardware.

My pods allocation preferring nodepool `A`. But, `A` is not always available. Its available 70% of the time.

Once a pod spawned in nodepool `B`, it will stay there forever. This is inefficient for me.

### Question:

I want to schedule auto termination of a pod, if its living inside of nodepool `B`. The auto termination can be done after a fix time (or even better random time between X to Y minutes).

How to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

The need is very clear.

You can add this piece of code to your Deployment (.spec.affinity.nodeAffinity):

```
    nodeAffinity:
      # Soft anti affinity between nodes A and B
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: nodepool-a
              operator: In
              values:
              - "true"
          topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

Assuming that the nodepool-a has a label "nodepool-a=true" (it could be any other), adding this configuration the Pods will be assigned to the nodepool-a; if nodepool-a is not available, they are scheduled on other nodepools that don't match the label.

With this configuration, you just need to schedule a rollout restart of your Deployment to move the Pods to nodepool-a when it is available.

Unfortunately there is no other way to achieve your goal; maybe you could automate the Deployment rollout restart triggered by a monitoring event, which after some time "notifies" that the nodepool-a is available.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/

Taking a look in the *nodeaffinity* code, I understand that the *requiredDuringSchedulingRequiredDuringExecution* function will be implemented which should even eviction Pods that are on nodes that do not match the label.

There are no details on when it will be implemented though.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.26.3/pkg/scheduler/framework/plugins/nodeaffinity/node_affinity.go#L36 (line 258)